# How to reshape matrices using index instead of shape inputs?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given an array of shape (8, 3, 4, 4), reshape them into an arbitrary new shape (8, 4, 4, 3) by inputting the new indices compared to the old positions (0, 2, 3, 1).

Comment: What is your question? You've given a "known solution"?

Comment: @roganjosh expecting cleaner, more readable solutions.

Comment: Get rid of the tuple?

Comment: @roganjosh I'll just post my solution as a separate answer to prevent these kinds of comment complaints then.

Comment: I don't know where you got "complaint" from when I just asked what your question _was_ given that you presented a solution. You didn't state that you wanted something cleaner; only after my "complaint" did you state that

Comment: @roganjosh no worries, just accustomed to stackoverflow's hostility here.

Comment: Part of that might be the perception of hostility. You misread my comment - could you be misreading others? You've come in expecting hostility and then managed to fabricate it from my innocent question. I would advise against this mindset because the directness of SO _would_ seem like a hostile place even when people are just trying to get to the point as quickly as possible

Comment: In any case, the tuple doesn't do anything for you here so I still suggest just using the values at the indices directly

Comment: The subject line suggested you wanted something like `arr[:, [0,0,1,2], :, :3]]`, an indexing operation.  But the (0,2,3,1) tuple is obviously a `transpose` argument.  I'm glad you 'discovered' transpose and its usefulness when doing `dot`, but what was the purpose of this question/answer?

Comment: `np.einsum` with 'ijkl,j' could be used instead of `dot`

Comment: @hpaulj I only luckily found out about transpose's permutation ability in a line of code from the chaotic codebase I'm working on right now, and then it lead me to the docs. Tried and searched for a couple of days now but couldn't find anything (perhaps because the idea I have of a permutation is different). It was a genuine simple question.

Thank you for the `einsum` discovery.

P.s.: subject line was worded how the issue first appeared to me. Perhaps I used the word "reshape" because the codebase used said method to solve the problem (in a very ugly way).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Numpy's `transpose` "reverses or permutes":

```
>>> mat = np.ones((8, 3, 4, 4))
>>> new_indices = (0, 2, 3, 1)
>>> mat.transpose(new_indices).shape
(8, 4, 4, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
arr = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]])
s = arr.shape
new_indexes = (1, 0, 2) # permutation
new_arr = arr.reshape(*[s[index] for index in new_indexes])

print(arr.shape) # (1, 3, 2)
print(new_arr.shape) # (3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: The thing is : you asked for a solution that permutates the matrix's shapes, but your solution seems to permutate the values, not the shape.
Furthermore, when running your code, I get "ValueError: axes don't match array"

Comment: No, it permutes the shape. I added the wrong example in my solution because it's been so long that I even forgot about the gist of it. I'll edit it.